# Why isn't my water pump giving enough pressure?

Tags: water-pressure, well-pump

I have an underground cistern with a submersible pump in Mexico. The pump went out for the second time. I think it was a crappy brand so I switched to a new one made by Truper.

The specs are downloadable here: https://www.truper.com/ficha_tecnica/Bomba-sumergible-tipo-bala-para-agua-limpia-1-2-HP-14061.html

[image]
[image]

The first pump was 1/2 hp and this one is as well. The pump is about 2m below the ground. At the ground level is a 35 gallon composite pressure tank with water bladder. About 1m above ground is a pressure gauge and 40/60 switch. The pressure tank, gauge and switch are all new, just in case those were the problem.

The pressure tank is about 38psi with no water.

When I turn on the pump at the switch, it starts pumping, but the pressure only goes up to about 45 on the gauge and the switch never trips. The pump will continue to run unless I shut it off manually. There are a couple filters but they are bypassed.

If it matters, this is a 2 story house with water access on the roof, so the highest faucet is about 10m above ground.

Why is the pressure so low? The only difference from the previous pump is that I switched from a 2 wire pump to a 3 wire, but it's rated the same and should have the same power. Could the wiring be wrong (I've checked it several times and appears right)

Also it seems that the air pressure on the top of the pressure tank was a little higher like 60, but it doesn't seem to have much water in it.

Comment: the wiring could be wrong, what is the voltage

Comment: It's 120v. There is a control box that splits the line into 2 lines, one has a capacitor on it that I think is for starting.

Comment: I see two possibilities, one the well is going dry or the pump is not capable of that pressure. I do not read spanish so the label does not help me but will help others.

Comment: The pump is always completely submerged with about 1m of water above it, which is in spec. It says it can pump up to 80m which should be about 120psi right?

Comment: Long story but I also had a 3/4 HP pump. I sent the 1/2 HP pump in for repair and put in the 3/4 just to see. This one went up to 60PSI, the same ration as the HP. So i guess this brand is just weak compared to the old one, even though it feels better constructed :/ no word back whether the 1/2 hp was not working well but i assume it was.